# Couldn't load image from http url by using nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Tags: android, github, android-imageview

I can load image from **https** url through Android-Universal-Image-Loader. But I couldn't load image from **http** url. Here am using "*universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar*"  from [This link nostra13](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) 
**The error shown in log**

```
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243): null
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243): java.io.EOFException
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:115)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:86)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:93)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:73)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:264)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:237)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:135)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-12 10:51:06.826: E/ImageLoader(2243):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Which Build version are you using.?

Comment: min 8 to max 21(lolipop)

Comment: From that stack trace, it feels like the server is closing the socket connection before the image is fully downloaded. Can you successfully visit your `http` URL in a browser on the device?

Comment: yes I can view the image through browser in device.

Comment: can you share your code

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this problem without changing one line of server code. What I did is replacing the default **URLConnectionImageDownloader** with **HttpClientImageDownloader**

Code sample:

```
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Turn off stale checking. Our connections break all the time anyway,
        // and it's not worth it to pay the penalty of checking every time.
        HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(params, false);
        // Default connection and socket timeout of 10 seconds. Tweak to taste.
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 10 * 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10 * 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192);

        // Don't handle redirects -- return them to the caller. Our code
        // often wants to re-POST after a redirect, which we must do ourselves.
        HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
        // Set the specified user agent and register standard protocols.
        HttpProtocolParams.setUserAgent(params, "some_randome_user_agent");
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

        ClientConnectionManager manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);


        ImageLoaderConfiguration config =
                new ImageLoaderConfiguration
                        .Builder(MainActivity.sharedMainActivity.getApplicationContext())
                        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                        .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
                        .threadPoolSize(1)
                        .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                        .imageDownloader(new HttpClientImageDownloader(new DefaultHttpClient(manager, params)))
                        .build();
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

For EOFException check the link.

http://code.google.com/p/libs-for-android/issues/detail?id=14.

```
 System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false").
```

Issue similar was raised and some suggested to try the above before opening HTTP url connection.

Probably has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score -2):

Check whether your URL. It may contains unexpected characters like newline ('\n' or '\r\n'), you will get EOFException when reading response. The newline will trunk HTTP packages and server thinks client has more data to send, so there is no response. Every attempt to read response will get EOF immediately.

After ensure your request is valid, I hope you will get you image.

Comment: I have even tried a normal cloud front URL `http://d3enzr1f6ar1e2.cloudfront.net/upload/64/image/BlackD.jpg` . Works with `https` not with `http`